# Node.js https.get return invalid json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, asynchronous

Any help is welcome, I have been struggling for many hours now...

I have a somewhat straight forward code in which I ping the GitHub API to retrieve a JSON. If I execute this code synchronously it works very well. However, when I receiving multiple call at the same time (or if I run it in async.parallel), sometimes the result of `aa` is an invalid JSON (I can see it in my logs) and JSON.parse crash. **It seems like there's a missing chunk in the final version of `aa`**

```
app.get('/update-tests', function(req, res) {
    const getOptionsGitHub = {
       ...
    };

    var req = https.get(getOptionsGitHub, function(res) {
        aa = "";
        res.on('data', function(chunk) { aa += chunk; });
        res.on('end', function() { 

            try {
                console.dir(aa);
                callback(JSON.parse(aa)); 
            } catch (e) {
                console.dir(e);
            }
        });
    });

    res.send(200);
});
```

Any idea why I would have some missing chunk sometimes?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but what is `callback`?

Comment: Because `aa` is a global.

Comment: This is why you should always have `"use strict";` at the start of the file... or at least run the code through a linter.

Comment: Change `aa = ""` to `var aa = ""`.

Comment: That's bad if examples on the web are using globals like that :/

Comment: -.- seems like it solved it. that's my bad, I didn't know that omitting "var" was making the variable public. Seems to be working now. Thanks a lot all! Feel free to post an official answer so I can accept it